# TeamCity Database Integration Tests

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I am setting up a TeamCity build to run some database related Nunit tests. These tests would need a Sql server connection to run. 
I am trying to pass such a connection string as a Test parameter.

I have created a build variable called

`Database_Connection_String` 
And I have set it to

```
Data Source=ANDROID-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDb;;User ID=TestDbAdmin;Password=***********
```

Further I have passed the test parameter to the Nunit3-console.exe in the following manner:

```
--params=TestDatabaseConnectionString=%Database_Connection_String%
```

After running the build, i am being shown the following error:

> [My_TEST_NAME]
>   OneTimeSetUp: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related
>   or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections.  (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:
>   26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The Sql server is running and I am able to connect to it using the same connection string from my app on the same machine. It is just that the Nunit tests are not picking up the connection string.

I have tried encapsulating the connection string with Double and Single quotes, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to pass connection string as a test parameter to the Nunit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to pass in a parameter containing a semi-colon with the `--params` option. This is something that will hopefully be fixed in time.

See the GitHub issue: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/23

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chris. We changed the configuration parameters and divided the database connection string into individual parameters like DataSource, InitialCatalog, Password and UserID. And then passed all these 4 parameters. Also made the required changes in the database integration tests, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: But it is still giving the same error message. We tried the solution on another TeamCity server and there it seem to be working fine. I mean, it is able to connect with the database, at least. However, it is failing to create the database because of permission issue. We gave all the required permissions and also tried using system admin ID and password but still it is giving permission issue.